# Google Sheets Script to automatically add (and update) a list of all sheets into a range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to pull a list of all sheets and update this list if something is changed in the workbook.

In my google sheet I am using the below function to place all sheets into a list:

```
=SHEETNAME()
```

With the script below I am aiming to update it at a change event:

```js
    function sheetName(e) {
      return SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheets()
        .map(function(sheet) {
          return sheet.getName();
        });
    }

    /*Create a installable trigger to listen to grid changes on the sheet*/
    function onChange(e) {
      if (!/GRID/.test(e.changeType)) return; //Listen only to grid change
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .createTextFinder('=SHEETNAME\\([^)]*\\)')
        .matchFormulaText(true)
        .matchCase(false)
        .useRegularExpression(true)
        .replaceAllWith(
          '=SHEETNAME(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1) + ')'
        );
    }
```

Have set up the below trigger - which also runs at change:
[image]

Yet unfortunately, the list is not automatically updated.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: To be sure of what you are intending to do. When a change happens to your Spreadsheet. For example you add a new row, you want to update the value of the list you previously had? I don't undertand what you are intending to do with ```.replaceAllWith(
      '=SHEETNAME(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1) + ')'
    );```

Comment: I am trying to add a random value into the "Sheetname" formula to force it to re-run and therefore update the sheet names at any change

Comment: This is a horribly expensive way to simply get a custom function to recalculate. Use a dummy cell reference in the formula that uses the custom function instead, and update the value in the dummy cell from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your installable Trigger, in order to do it, follow these steps:

1) Go to your Apps Script project

2) Click Edit->Current project's triggers

3) Click "+ Add Trigger"

4) Select :

- Choose which function to run -> *Function Name*
- Select event source-> From spreadsheet
- Select event type -> On change

Now, I modified your `onChange` function a little because otherwise, you would enter in an infinite loop

```js
function sheetName(e) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheets()
    .map(function(sheet) {
      return sheet.getName();
    });
}

/*Create a installable trigger to listen to grid changes on the sheet*/
function onChange(e) {
  Logger.log(e.changeType)
  if (/GRID/.test(e.changeType)){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder('=SHEETNAME\\([^)]*\\)')
    .matchFormulaText(true)
    .matchCase(false)
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .replaceAllWith(
      '=SHEETNAME(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1) + ')'
    );
  }
}
```

### Docs

These are the docs I used to help you:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).
- [Change Event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change).

Comment: Why do you think it'll run in a infinite loop?

Comment: I tested the code and the if condition didn't work in the right way because the ```return``` keyword doesn't work in the ```onChange``` function so it would still run the next code's section and by editing the sheet's names it would trigger again the  ```onChange``` function

Answer (score 0):

Your function name needs to be `onEdit(e)`.

See [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) about triggers from Google dev.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it, yet unfortunately no luck.